# Cannot create TABLE with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what's happening here but I cannot seem to create the table.

Is this a syntax error or something else?

When I tried to paste the `CREATE TABLE` part into the SQL part on `PHPMyAdmin`, I had to tinker with the syntax a bit before it worked.

What I want to be able to do it via PHP directly.

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);

if  (!$conn){
    echo "Failed to connect to Server";
}else{
    echo "Connected";
}

$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE college';
$table = 'CREATE TABLE students(
student_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
student_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
student_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
student_city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
)';

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo"Database created";
    }else{
    echo 'Failed to create Database';
};

if(mysqli_query($conn,$table)){
    echo "Table Created";
}else{
    echo "Failed to create Table";
};
```

Comment: I think you have to select the database you are wanting to create the table in. Between your "create database" and your "create table", you have to make something like `mysqli_select_db($conn,'college');`

Comment: You're not selecting DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After create database successfully to need to select database then use  create statement

```
mysqli_select_db ( $conn ,  'college' );// select database first
if(mysqli_query($conn,$table)){
    echo "Table Created";
}else{
    echo "Failed to create Table";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma in the end of the below line inside the `CREATE TABLE`

```
student_city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

it will cause the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1